# React how to map through data to display image for styled component prop?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

So I have an image slider that maps through data and displays my images

```
{SliderData.map((slide, index) => {
    return (
           <Section>
            <h1>{slide.title}</h1>
            <Image src={slide.image} alt={slide.alt} />
           </Section>
            );
 })}
```

And my data file looks like this

```
 export const SlideData = [
  {
   title: 'title',
   alt: 'alt',
   image: './images/image-1.jpg'
  },
   {
   title: 'title 2',
   alt: 'alt 2',
   image: './images/image-2.jpg'
  },
 ]
```

My issue is how would I pass the image into a styled component instead of hard coding it in my JSX?

```
 const Section = styled.section`
   background: url(${image});
 `
```

Something like this where I just pass the image into the styled component. What I don't understand is how would my data be mapped through for each slide if I pass it into the styled component?

I can't figure out how I would be able to read the data file of all my images since the image value is passed into the styled component `background` property?

I want to pass my slider images through this method because it allows me to style the design a specific way that I can't do when I hard code it into my JSX.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This could work out

```js
<Section bg={bgPath} alt="logo" />

const Section= styled.section`
   background-image: url(${(props) => props.bg});   
`;
```

Comment: what is signin?

Comment: It's a background image path.

Comment: but how would you get multiple images if there's more than one? I need to map through a list of multiple images, not just display one image

Answer (score -1):

Ok I think this is what you are talking about:

```
<Section image={image}></Section>
```

Then:

```
const Section = styled.section`
   background: url(${(props) => props.image || 'fallback-image.jpg' }) center;
```

Documentation:

1. https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props

Comment: Why is there still an <Image> tag? if you pass the image into the styled component the image tag wouldn't exist